# MYSQL inserting UNC time into a column, yet getting errors

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a UTC timestamp into a row in mysql by using MySQLWorkBench. I have set the column type as TIMESTAMP, BIGINT, INT and TIME. No matter what I set it as I receive the same error - "incorrect (Type Here) value".

I am using this code to test this:

```
INSERT INTO mytablenamehere (`Time`) VALUES ('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3))')
```

Should add I am on MYSQL 8.0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sometimes Workbench and mysql server has issues esp. if you are using higher version workbench and your mysql server is old version, try to run your code in mysql cli.

Comment: Thanks. mysql version 8 actually. I can try to download something else. This is the proper way yes?

Comment: instead of WorkBench maybe you can try use HeidiSQL
https://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: happens in myphpadmin too:/

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` then [post the result](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65605747/edit) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to insert a string. Your query should be `VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3)))` (without the single quotes). Also note that (from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)):

> The return value is an integer if no argument is given or the argument does not include a fractional seconds part, or DECIMAL if an argument is given that includes a fractional seconds part.

So your column must be either an INT or a DOUBLE, depending on the precision you want.

Comment: Thank you. In going back to setting the column type as INT and removing the quotes from the VALUE, I Am now getting an error that my primary key - which auto increments - and is an ID set to an INT, does not have a default value.